# jquery not running php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've found some code that allows me to upload photos using using $_files

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<form class="topmenu" action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

        <div style="display:inline-block; position:relative; top:2px;" >
            <input class="ui-btn" type="file" name="file" id="file">    
        </div>

        <div style="display:inline-block; position:relative; top:-10px;" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
            <a href="logout.php" class="ui-btn" >Logout</a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and in upload_file.php

```
<?php

ob_start();

// Connect to server and select databse.
$link = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name")or die("cannot connect"); 
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "JPG");

if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']))
{
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);

    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    ||($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") 
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") 
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
        {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

            if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) 
            {
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            } 
            else 
            {
                $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (name, type, size) VALUES ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link , $_FILES["file"]["name"]) . "','" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link , $_FILES["file"]["type"]) . "','" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link , $_FILES["file"]["size"]) . "')";

                if (!mysqli_query($link,$sql)) 
                {
                    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
                }

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            }

            header("location:main_login.php");
        }
    }
}
else
{
    if ( !empty($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']) && empty($_FILES) && empty($_POST) )
    {
        echo 'The uploaded zip was too large. You must upload a file smaller than ' . ini_get("upload_max_filesize");
    }

}
?>
```

but now I've add Jquery Mobile ui buttons from here       http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_buttons.asp
and now when I press submit/upload, I get taken to upload_file.php but it's just a white screen. As far as I can tell nothing is happening! if I remove the jquery stuff it starts working again, but the site looks a bit naff.

Comment: what's the code you use when you add the jquery mobile button ?

Comment: We need to see the problematic code as well. It's probably not sending the file data for some reason.

Comment: The title is a bit confusing. PHP runs on the server, and it's independent of your jQuery

Comment: You quite probably want to turn off `ajax navigation` that a **biG part** of jQuery Mobile. Once that's done, everything should work fine.

Comment: @ClemSndr all I've done is added the Script with the src pointing at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js and http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js.

Comment: @user3558931 thank you. A quick search and that's sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Please turn off `ajax navigation` that's a **biG part** of jQuery Mobile. Once that's done, everything should work fine. With ajax navigation on pages are added to the DOM rather than navigated to. Therefore form submissions would not work the way you expect them to.

```
Ref: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.4/navigation/
     http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/
```